# Use JQuery to set css file body background url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change my body's background dynamically in a jQuery window resize event.
The below is a simplified example that attempts to set the body background url property when the page loads, but its not the right syntax.  Any ideas?

test.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue;
}
```

test.html's JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").css("background", "url('image/setme.png')");
  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd try being explicit about the property:

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url('image/setme.png')");
```

Comment: I agree that `background-image` is probably a better choice but it isn't necessary (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AsJqg/), c12 probably just has a problem with the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

if no image is showing plz try this, access image from root directory

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url('../image/setme.png')");
```

or

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url('~/image/setme.png')");
```

Comment: I'd guess that `/image/setme.png` is the right one but I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $("body").css("background", "url(image/setme.png)");
});
```

to trigger the resize event?

Comment: yeah thats right wizztjh, I just wanted to take that out of the way as that works fine.  Wanted to simplify it even more.